# How you make rounded corners for side drawer menu in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, css-position

I am new in Ionic. I am stuck on rounded corners for the side drawer menu. Please give me a solution if it works then I accept your answer Anyone here with a solution for this? Thanks in Advance. Here is my code.

```
.menu-inner {
   border-radius: 0px 50px 0px 0px !important;
}
```

in Inspect element this is perfect work but not work in code
 here is screen short

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, You can not style `shadow-root` element in the DOM by using CSS. In some cases, the CSS4 helps to style. But in this case, it would not work.

So, You can use JavaScript to style `shadow-root` element. Here You should create a simple method like `menuRadius` and call it in `initializeApp` in the following way.

> src/app/app.component.ts

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.menuRadius(); // call menuRadius method
    });
  }
  menuRadius() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.querySelector('ion-menu').shadowRoot.querySelector('.menu-inner').setAttribute('style', 'border-radius:0px 50px 0px 0px');
    }, 2000);
  }
```

**Please Note** Injecting style by using JavaScript only works when `shadow-root` is `open`.

You may check this [article](https://www.joshmorony.com/shadow-dom-usage-in-ionic-web-components/) for more info about `shadow-root` DOM.